# In react , addEventListner does not work properly with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, onclick, addeventlistener

I have used a div and click eventListner on it. My intention is to log value of count after each increment.
But it is not happening

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'

export default function LOL() {

    const [count,setCount] = useState(0);
    const divRef = useRef(null);

    const handleCount = () =>{
        setCount(prev=>prev+1);
    }

    // Add event Listner to the div
    useEffect(()=>{
        const div = divRef.current;

        const handleCount2 = () =>{
            setCount(prev=>prev+1);
        }

        div.addEventListener('click', handleCount);
        return(
            div.removeEventListener('click', handleCount)
        );
    },[])
    // Print value of count after each change
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(count);
    },[count])

  return (
    <div ref = {divRef} style={
        {
            width:'500px', height:'500px',backgroundColor:'black'
        }
    }>

    </div>
  )
}
```

- If I use code as it is , it will print only zero (in both function hadleCount and handleCount2) it wont work, dont know why
- If i make removeEventListner disappear it works perfectly for handleCount but for handleCount 2 it will print 2 times each with increment( like instead of 1 it will be 1 2)
- if i make Event Listner useEffect run every time it behave like above but on staroid

**I know i should not be using DOM element in react but addEventListner are sometime required in special cases**

Comment: small correction for the clean-up of effect, it should be `return () => {
            div.removeEventListener('click', handleCount);
        };`

Comment: You remove the handler immediately

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use the useEffect hook to add event listener, you should return a function:

```js
 useEffect(()=>{
        const div = divRef.current;

        const handleCount2 = () =>{
            setCount(prev=>prev+1);
        }

        div.addEventListener('click', handleCount);
        return ()=> {
        div.removeEventListener('click', handleCount);
        }
    },[])
```

but the easiest approach would be to use the `onClick` function of the `div` like that:

```js
    <div
    onClick={setCount(count + 1)}
    style={{ width:'500px', height:'500px',backgroundColor:'black' }
    }>
```